# SQLite group by total sales per month

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, datetime

I know this question has been answered before but my query works on another table in my database but not on the table I am trying to work on. It is returning the total sales regardless of months but i want aggregate sales by month.

My query is:

```
select COUNT(orderid),
strftime("%m/%Y", orderDate) as 'month-year'
from customerOrders group by strftime("%m/%Y", orderDate)
```

My result is:

```
COUNT(orderid)  month-year
17              Null
```

My database format is:
[Database Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/292q9.png)

Comment: Change the format of the dates to YYYY-MM-DD and the code will work.

Answer (score 0):

try avoid minus and single quote for column name

```
 select COUNT(orderid),
 strftime("%m/%Y", orderDate) as  month_year
 from customerOrders 
 group by strftime("%m/%Y", orderDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `orderDate` column format of your dates is incorrect for sqlite to do `strftime()`. Change from `%d/%m/%Y` to `%Y-%m-%d`.